# Are there any missable trophies?

Tags: achievements, final-fantasy-13-2

Final Fantasy 13 had some trophies that required you to collect items that could be missed, and would require you to start a brand new game if you wanted to collect the item, does Final Fantasy 13-2 have any such trophies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No there are no such trophies in the game.
There are a few that require you to close gates and replay the area but no trophies that you absolutely cannot get after passing that area.